# Perl Merge file

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I have 3 or multiple files I need to merge, the data looks like this..

```
file 1
0334.45656
0334.45678
0335.67899
file 2
0334.89765
0335.12346
0335.56789
file 3
0334.12345
0335.45678
0335.98764
```

Expected output in file 4,

```
0334.89765
0334.89765
0334.89765
0334.12345
0335.67899
0335.12346
0335.56789
0335.45678
0335.98764
```

So far I have tried but data in 4rth file does not come in sorted order,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my %hash;
my $outFile = "outFile.txt";
foreach $file(@ARGV)
{
print "$file\n";
open (IN, "$file") || die "cannot open file $!";
open (OUT,">>$outFile") || die "cannot open file $!";
while ( <IN> )
{
    chomp $_;
    ($timestamp,$data) = split (/\./,$_);
    $hash{$timeStamp}{'data'}=$data;
    if (defined $hash{$timeStamp})
    {
    print "$_\n";
    print OUT"$_\n";

        }
}
}
close (IN);
close (OUT);
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't normally suggest this, but unix utilties should be able to handle this just fine.

1. `cat` the 3 files together.
2. use `sort` to sort the merged file.

However, using perl, could just do the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @data;
push @data, $_ while (<>);

# Because the numbers are all equal length, alpha sort will work here
print for sort @data;
```

However, as we've discussed, it's possible that the files will be extremely large.  Therefore it will be more efficient both in memory and speed if you're able to take advantage of the fact that all the files are already sorted.

The following solution therefore streams the files, pulling out the next one in order each loop of the while:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Could name this catsort.pl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

# Initialize File handles
my @fhs = map {open my $fh, '<', $_; $fh} @ARGV;

# First Line of each file
my @data = map {scalar <$_>} @fhs;

# Loop while a next line exists
while (@data) {
    # Pull out the next entry.
    my $index = (sort {$data[$a] cmp $data[$b]} (0..$#data))[0];

    print $data[$index];

    # Fill In next Data at index.
    if (! defined($data[$index] = readline $fhs[$index])) {
        # End of that File
        splice @fhs, $index, 1;
        splice @data, $index, 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any shell script longer than three lines should be a perl script... though as you hint at, this would be a two line long shell script and is perfectly appropriate for such.

Comment: Thanks! I know, in unix would do it really easily, I would like to know how can I do it in Perl?

Comment: is there any way we can do this by taking data in memory in like hash and then try to match the incoming data and then put it in OUT file?

Comment: @efficasy Yes, pretty much anything is possible, it's just a matter of coding it.  Assuming you're previous files are sorted, it should be possible to stream the incoming files and sort them as we go.  Maybe I'll code something like that for fun in a moment.

Comment: Please note, your expected output isn't actually sorted.  The left numbers is in ascending order, but the right number appears to be a random order.  Is this a mistype of your question?  Or is there an order that that I'm unable to decode.

Comment: The whole line should be sorted based on the first column. I.e. first column should be sorted and its corresponding data should match.

Comment: Does it matter if the 2nd column is sorted as well?  Is the first column always 4 digits long followed by a period?

Comment: if the first column is sorted then corresponding data should match as well.

Comment: Then look at your expected output in your question.  You have the following numbers in a list:  `0335.67899`, `0335.12346`, `0335.56789`.    Is your sample output wrong then?

Comment: the second column dosent matter if its in sorted order or not..it corresponds to the first column.. and needs no sorting. As long as first column is sorted the second column should go along with it. Many thanks for helping me on this.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're wanting to stream the sorting?  Are the files excessively large or something?  Did you try using unix cat & sort to solve this problem?  Why are you insisting on a perl solution?

Comment: The files are really large. May be in gigs.. thats why wondering if there is something less CPU intensive i can write...

Comment: I've added a second perl script that streams the merged files and sorts them line by line.  As long as the original files are also sorted, this should work.  Note, I chose to print to STDOUT, so just need to direct the output to file of choice.

Answer (score 2):

Using Miller's idea in a more reusable way,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub get_sort_iterator {
  my @fhs = map {open my $fh, '<', $_ or die $!; $fh} @_;
  my @d;

  return sub {
    for my $i (0 .. $#fhs) {
      # skip to next file handle if it doesn't exists or we have value in $d[$i]
      next if !$fhs[$i] or defined $d[$i];

      # reading from $fhs[$i] file handle was success?
      if ( defined($d[$i] = readline($fhs[$i])) ) { chomp($d[$i]) }
      # file handle at EOF, not needed any more
      else  { undef $fhs[$i] }
    }
    # compare as numbers, return undef if no more data
    my ($index) = sort {$d[$a] <=> $d[$b]} grep { defined $d[$_] } 0..$#d
      or return;

    # return value from $d[$index], and set it to undef
    return delete $d[$index];
  };
}

my $iter = get_sort_iterator(@ARGV);
while (defined(my $x = $iter->())) {
  print "$x\n";
}
```

output

```
0334.12345
0334.45656
0334.45678
0334.89765
0335.12346
0335.45678
0335.56789
0335.67899
0335.98764
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose every input files are already in ascending order and have at least one line in them, this script could merge them in ascending order:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use List::Util 'reduce';

sub min_index {
    reduce { $_[$a] < $_[$b] ? $a : $b } 0 .. $#_;
}

my @fhs = map { open my $fh, '<', $_; $fh } @ARGV;
my @data = map { scalar <$_> } @fhs;

while (@data) {
    my $idx = min_index(@data);
    print "$data[$idx]";
    if (! defined($data[$idx] = readline $fhs[$idx])) {
        splice @data, $idx, 1;
        splice @fhs, $idx, 1;
    }
}
```

---

Note: this is basic the same as the second script offered by @Miller, but a bit clearer and more concise.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this solution, which uses a sorted array of hashes - each hash corresponding to an input file, and containing a file handle `fh`, the last line read `line` and the timestamp extracted from the line `timestamp`.

The hash at the end of the array always corresponds to the input that has the smallest value for the timestamp, so all that is necessary is to repeateedly `pop` the next value from the array, `print` its data, read the next line and (if it hasn't reached eof) insert it back into the array in sorted order.

This could produce an appreciable increase in speed over the repeated sorting of all the data for each output line that other answers use.

Note that the program expects the list of input files as parameters on the command line, and sends its merged output to STDOUT. It also assumes that the input files are already sorted.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @data;

for my $file (@ARGV) {
  my $item;
  open $item->{fh}, '<', $file;
  insert_item($item, \@data);
}

while (@data) {
  my $item = pop @data;
  print $item->{line};
  insert_item($item, \@data);
}

sub insert_item {
  my ($item, $array) = @_;
  return if eof $item->{fh};
  $item->{line} = readline $item->{fh};
  ($item->{timestamp}) = $item->{line} =~ /^(\d+)/;
  my $i = 0;
  ++$i while $i < @$array and $item->{timestamp} < $array->[$i]{timestamp};
  splice @$array, $i, 0, $item;
}
```

**output**

```
0334.45656
0334.89765
0334.12345
0334.45678
0335.12346
0335.45678
0335.67899
0335.56789
0335.98764
```