# Optimise the removal of duplicate lines from a large file

Tags: python

How can I optimise this code. I want to remove a duplicate lines from a file but think using the set if inefficient and will limit the size of file I can parse.

```
file = open("sample.txt")

output = []
alreadyseen = set()    

while True:
    lines = file.readlines(100000)
    if not lines:
        break
    for line in lines:
        pass # do something
        if line not in alreadyseen:
            output.append(line)
            alreadyseen.add(line)
    print(output)
```

Comment: How big is the file? What about a binary search tree (which will give you Log N lookups)? Alternately, if the lines are sorted, you could iterate and remember only the previous line...?

Comment: If it will all fit in memory, the technique you have here is probably optimal. If you're interested in a method that works even if it doesn't fit, just say so.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `print(output)` outside the loop?

Comment: Do you care about the order of the lines?

Comment: @erewok a set is hash based giving O(1) lookups vs. a tree at O(log n).

Comment: @MarkRansom: I didn't read the question well enough and just now saw that he was using a set. Was going to edit my comment, but I'll leave it for consistency now.

Comment: Optimization is always a compromise between speed vs memory footprint. What kind are you looking for?

Comment: If file fits in memory, then your approach seems to be okay. If not then you can check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623472/remove-all-duplicates-in-a-large-text-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is likely to be the fastest way to do this, but as you noted it will be limited by the number of lines you can fit in memory. There are some techniques that will mitigate that problem and allow you to process much larger files.

The first is to only read and write one line at a time. There's no need to read a chunk of 100000 at a time since you're processing them individually, and certainly no reason to hold all the unique results in a single string. Read and write one line at a time to minimize waste.

The second is to substitute a cryptographic hash for a longer string. The hash will be a fixed size, no matter how long the line itself is. If you're worried about the possibility of two strings producing the same hash, don't be - with a large enough hash the probability of two strings producing the same hash is lower than the probability of a RAM glitch that allows two different string to compare equal, even taking into consideration the [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Combining both approaches looks something like this:

```
import hashlib

sha256 = hashlib.sha256()
alreadyseen = set()
with open("sample.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        pass # do something
        key = line if len(line) < 32 else sha256(line)
        if key not in alreadyseen:
            alreadyseen.add(key)
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

write to a temp file to avoid storing all the lines in the list then just reopen both files and update `file1` with contents of `file2`:

```
alreadyseen = set()
with open(file_1) as f1, open(file_2, "w") as f2:
    while True:
        lines = f1.readlines(100000)
        if not lines:
            break
        for line in lines:
            pass # do something
            if line not in alreadyseen:
                f2.write(line)
                alreadyseen.add(line)

with open(file1, "w") as f1, open(file_2) as f2:
    for line in f2:
        f1.write(line)
```