# Merging mutiple log files by timestamp in 2nd column

Tags: regex, perl

I have multiple logfiles for same day . What I want to do is to merge them in to single one based on timestamp in logs using `Perl` script.

**Log-1.log**

```
2014-06-02 21:54:38,805 INFO  com.HomeManeger [Executor:Thread-19]: MyInfo started for myid=TEST-401406
2014-06-02 21:56:27,358 INFO  com.HomeManeger [Executor:Thread-13]: HomeManeger: populateMyInfo completed for my id = TEST-401406,  
2014-06-02 21:59:32,358 INFO  com.HomeManeger [Executor:Thread-17]: MyInfo completed for myid=TEST-401405
```

**Log-2.log:**

```
2014-06-02 21:56:27,295 INFO  com.homeManeger.MyCommand [Proxy:ProxyService:TcpWorker:2]:     MyCommand::Processing reqest[AB:MyInfo] obj(Collection [ID={005A004A5B0F9}, ]
) client(POFFBObj [ID={XXXXXX-E8F5-11D5-YYY-0002B33D9D0C}, meta={}, fields=[XXX]]
)
2014-06-02 21:58:27,310 INFO  com.HomeManeger.UpdateMyInfoTask
```

**Merged Log:**

```
2014-06-02 21:54:38,805 INFO  com.HomeManeger [Executor:Thread-19]: MyInfo started for myid=TEST-401406
2014-06-02 21:56:27,295 INFO  com.homeManeger.MyCommand [Proxy:ProxyService:TcpWorker:2]: MyCommand::Processing reqest[AB:MyInfo] obj(Collection[ID={005A004A5B0F9}, ]
) client(POFFBObj [ID={XXXXXX-E8F5-11D5-YYY-0002B33D9D0C}, meta={}, fields=[XXX]]
)
2014-06-02 21:56:27,358 INFO  com.HomeManeger [Executor:Thread-13]: HomeManeger: populateMyInfo completed for my id = TEST-401406,  
2014-06-02 21:56:32,358 INFO  com.HomeManeger [Executor:Thread-17]: MyInfo completed for myid=TEST-401405    
2014-06-02 21:58:27,310 INFO  com.HomeManeger.UpdateMyInfoTask
```

I am very new to `Perl` ,any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have just discovered the right tool for the job in python is pandas. Data manipulation library with clever file IO methods and database style merge/join. Is there a library that can do this in perl? PDL? Other? Not really. The right tool needs two things: 1. FILE READ/WRITE data formats. 2. data indexing structures and manipulation methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following script can process any number of log files and output the merged log to a file.

It will load them all into memory so size is a factor:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

die "Usage: perl $0 log1 log2 > merged.log\n" if !@ARGV;

my @lines;

while (<>) {
    if (/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/) {
        push @lines, $_;
    } else {
        $lines[-1] .= $_;
    }
}

print sort @lines;
```

If memory is a factor, you'll need to do an official merge sort.

The following was adapted from [`perl merge sort`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22586131/1733163) from March of this year:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

die "Usage: perl $0 log1 log2 > merged.log\n" if !@ARGV;

# Initialize File handles
my @fhs = map {open my $fh, '<', $_; $fh} @ARGV;

# First Line of each file
my @data = map {scalar <$_>} @fhs;

# Loop while a next line exists
while (@data) {
    # Pull out the next entry.
    my $index = (sort {$data[$a] cmp $data[$b]} (0..$#data))[0];

    print $data[$index];

    # Fill In next Data at index.
    while (defined($data[$index] = readline $fhs[$index])) {
        last if $data[$index] =~ /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/;
        print $data[$index];
    }

    # End of that File
    if (! defined($data[$index]) {
        splice @fhs, $index, 1;
        splice @data, $index, 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: any idea how can I overcome memory factor ? because my logs size is ~50MB.

Comment: 50MB isn't that big.  However, yes, you'll have to do an actual merge sort if memory is a factor.  I've included added untested code that will do that.

Comment: Thanks , It works but with one small issue. few logs ( like 2014-06-02 21:59:32,358)is not appneded in new line instead they are in same line.

Comment: Your criticism doesn't really make any sense.  Wanna try explaining again?

Comment: If i run this code against above two logs file then in merged.log I am getting one line as `2014-06-02 21:58:27,310 INFO  com.HomeManeger.UpdateMyInfoTask2014-06-02 21:59:32,358 INFO  com.HomeManeger [Executor:`

Comment: The only reason I can think that would happen is if one of your log files did not have a new line after the final line in the log.  Is that the case?  And if so, is this a real log file, or is this just constructed test data, and therefore the real log file will always have a trailing newline?

Comment: If I already have array of files how can I pass that to while loop instead of <> ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
cat file1 file2 | sort > out
```

Comment: Order is not correct where new line doesn't have timestamp

Comment: How can a line not have a timestamp?  Is it OK to preprocess such lines by appending them to the previous line with a timestamp?

Comment: One log may contain new line with additional data.In such case Appending to previous line is the desired result though.

Comment: @reinierpost :    `2014-06-02 21:56:27,295 INFO  com.homeManeger.MyCommand [Proxy:ProxyService:TcpWorker:2]: MyCommand::Processing reqest[AB:MyInfo] obj(Collection[ID={005A004A5B0F9}, ]
) client(POFFBObj [ID={XXXXXX-E8F5-11D5-YYY-0002B33D9D0C}, meta={}, fields=[XXX]]
)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Time::Piece;
use autodie;

my $fmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';

my @files=qw(Log-1.log Log-2.log);

my @lines;

for my $file (@files) {
   open(my $fh, "<", $file);
   while (my $line=<$fh>) {
      my ($data)=$line=~/^(\S+\s+\S+?),/;
      my $k = Time::Piece->strptime($data, $fmt);
      push(@lines,{key=>$k, line=>$line});
   }
   close($fh);
}
for (sort {$a->{key} <=> $b->{key}} @lines) {
   print $_->{line};
}
```

Comment: I dont have Piece module installed so couldn't use this script .

Answer (score 0):

you could use advanced log merge but it only works on windows
http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Miscellaneous/Advanced-Logs-Merge.shtml